A disk of mass m and radius R rolls without slipping on rough horizontal plane. Make a dynamic equation for it balance
A disk of mass m and radius R rolls without slipping on rough horizontal plane. Make a dynamic equation for it balance. Could you any methods
For this system, where two coordinate systems are introduced - Euler and Lagrangian, we will consider the main aspects.

1. **Eulerian Oxyz coordinate system**:
    - Located in the Oxy plane.
    - The k axis is directed opposite to the true vertical.

2. **Lagrangian coordinate system Oξηζ**:
    - The axes of this system are the central principal axes of inertia of the ball.

According to the given limitation of the movement of the disk, we know that its center of mass moves along a fixed plane, and there is no slippage, that is, the point of contact k moves with zero speed.

The instantaneous angular velocity vector can be represented as the sum of the angular velocity vectors along each of the coordinate axes:

\[ \mathbf{\omega} = \omega_\xi \mathbf{\xi} + \omega_\eta \mathbf{\eta} + \omega_\zeta \mathbf{\zeta} \]

where \( \omega_\xi, \omega_\eta, \omega_\zeta \) are the components of the instantaneous angular velocity vector relative to the corresponding coordinate axes \( \xi, \eta, \zeta \).

This describes the motion of the sphere in the Lagrangian coordinate system.

Due to the absence of slippage, the velocity of the contact point \( v_M \) is zero. Thus, the instantaneous velocity vector \( \mathbf{v}_M \) is expressed through the instantaneous angular velocity vector \( \mathbf{\omega} \) and the radius vector \( \mathbf{r}_{CM} \) of the point center of mass:

\[ \mathbf{v}_M = \mathbf{v}_{CM} + \mathbf{\omega} \times \mathbf{r}_{CM} \]

where \( \mathbf{v}_{CM} \) is the velocity of the center of mass, which has only a component in the direction of the \( \zeta \) axis.

I'm stuck here... any thoughts how to solve?
